# Confusing Makefile

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, directory

I just came across this makefile, and it's confusing to me:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = ../..

LIBDIR = $(PROJECT_ROOT)/src/lib

INCDIR = $(PROJECT_ROOT)/include

SRCS = proj_start.c  function1.c
LIBS = $(LIBDIR)/libtest.a

OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
PROJECT = project1
FLAGS = -I$(INCDIR)
CC = gcc $(FLAGS)

.c.o:
        $(CC) -c $<

$(PROJECT): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o $@

it: $(PROJECT)

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) $(PROJECT)

depend: $(SRCS)
        $(CC) -M $(SRCS) > dependList
        sed -e '1,/^# DO NOT DELETE/!d' Makefile > make.tmp
        cat dependList >> make.tmp
        mv make.tmp Makefile
        rm dependList

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE
```

These are the parts that confuse me:

```
LIBDIR = $(PROJECT_ROOT)/src/lib
```

Why is LIBDIR in the root/src/lib library? 
Shouldn't it be the root/lib directory (both directories are present in the file hierarchy)?

```
.c.o:
        $(CC) -c $<
```

What the heck does this do? The "$<" evaluates to .c.o? I see that it is a 'suffix rule' but what are they really used for?

```
depend: $(SRCS)
        $(CC) -M $(SRCS) > dependList
        sed -e '1,/^# DO NOT DELETE/!d' Makefile > make.tmp
        cat dependList >> make.tmp
        mv make.tmp Makefile
        rm dependList

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE
```

Why do we need this part? It seems all the dependencies have already been handled...?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yeah, putting `lib/` under `src/` looks like a bad, counterintuitive design.
2. This:

   .c.o:
       ...

is [the old way](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules) of writing an implicit rule. These days we'd write it like this:

```
%.o: %.c
    ...
```

3. It's a slightly Rube Goldberg (i.r. clever but over-complicated) way of doing automatic dependency handling. So if `foo.c` contains the line `#include bar.h`, this rule will append the line `foo.o: bar.h` to the makefile. This is actually important.